# Mocking Modules in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I have a method in App.js for which I want to write test cases. But when I import App.js in the test file all the import statements inside App.js are also getting imported and causing an error. Is it possible to mock a dependency which is imported insde my App.js using jest. Consider the example below

```
//App.js 
import user from '../user.js';
//some functions which needs to be tested
```

Is it possible to mock user.js when I try in my App.spec.js file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sinonjs https://sinonjs.org/how-to/stub-dependency/

sinon.stub(user, 'functionToMock').callsFake(() => {})

Answer (score 0):

You could simply mock any user module in the jest by the following statement.

```
jest.mock('./moduleName')
```

for further understanding, you could refer to the following document.

[https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#:~:text=When%20a%20manual%20mock%20exists,moduleName'](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#:%7E:text=When%20a%20manual%20mock%20exists,moduleName%27)